# how to depend form a string in android

Tags: android

I have a question is there a way or a script to depend a string?
I will give a example of what i want:

```
String oldstring = "123";
String newstring = depend(oldstring);
```

I want my var newstring to equal 12.
What do I need to do?

Comment: Umm... what do you mean?  newString is a String, so how could it become 12?  What is this depend?  Is this a parsing question?

Comment: The question cannot be answered. Do you want to truncate the final character from the source string? Or take the first two characters from it? Do you want an integer 12 or a string "12" out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take parts of a string, use stringName.substring() : http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/SubstringExample.shtml

If you want to get an integer from a string, use Integer.parseInt(string) : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

"I want my var newstring to equal 12. What do I need to do?" No vars in java btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want it to be "12" then use String.SubString(0,2) method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 12 is a typo.  And by depend I am assuming a pointer.  You cannot use pointers for strings in Java.

If you just want to assign oldstring to newstring, then:

String newstring = oldstring;